# append data two time to the table when get data from controller(jquery ajax)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ajaxq

recently i encountered with the confused proplem.

i want to lazy loading according to the  bellow link:
[ASP.NET MVC Infinite Scrolling Jquery](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1108916/ASP-NET-MVC-Infinite-Scrolling-Jquery)

when run project and used a feature that implemented . everything is working properly but jquery not .
it append my data two time see image:
[pay attention to first field which is a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df8Jm.jpg)

every thing is ok (firebug illustrate correct data)
but what was happen there.

my jquery code is :

```js
var page = 1;
var scrollHandler = function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()))
        loadMoreToInfiniteScrollTable();

}

function loadMoreToInfiniteScrollTable() {
    page++;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: dataUrl,
        data: "p=" + page,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('tbody').append( data );
                
        }
        }
    });
    
}
```

calling method

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dataUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("UserInfo")';
        $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
    </script>
```

controller action methods :
its populate view for once

```
    public List<inf> lst;
    public ActionResult ExpressionDetail()
    {
        var data = lst.Where(f=>f.id>0&&f.id<lenght).OrderBy(i=>i.id);

        return View(data);
    }
```

and the partial view for page sepration:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult _TableData(int? p=0)
    {
        int firstfrom = p ?? 1;
        int endfrom = (firstfrom > 1 ? (firstfrom - 1) * lenght : 0);

        var g= lst.OrderBy(i=>i.id).Skip(endfrom-1).Take(lenght).AsEnumerable();

        return PartialView(g);
    }
```

route config:

```
routes.MapRoute("UserInfo", "",new {Controller= "Default", Action= "_TableData" });
```

const lenght:

```
public const int lenght = 15;
```

partialview:

```
@model IEnumerable<testable.Models.inf>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>

</tr>
```

}

and main view:

```
@model IEnumerable<testable.Models.inf>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>ExpressionDetail</title>
</head>
<body>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
    </tr>
@Html.Partial("_TableData", Model)
    <tbody>

    </tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

inf model

```
public class inf
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show the controller method your calling and the view it returns (and look ate the html your generating - best guess is you have multiple `<tbody>` elements

Comment: yes sir , im show controller method , my calling is the second part of javascript that shows above, i dont mean multiple tbody plz show me

Comment: You still have not shown you partial view :) And what is the value of `lenght` (I assume its 10?)

Comment: lenght is a const value which can be a 15 or another , i updated the post now

Comment: You still have not shown your partial view :)

Comment: Change the ajax callback to `$('tbody').append($(data).find('tr'));` but some of the code in you controller makes no sense anyway - (for example your parameter is nullable `int` but you provide a default for it so it can never be `null`)

Comment: i was update the code you offer but no data affected(no data insert to the table) when scrolling

Comment: I have just seen you latest edit - the main view does not make sense either - your `@Html.Partial("_TableData", Model)` should be inside the `<tbody>` elements (you are generating multiple `<tbody>` elements so when you scroll you add the data twice)

Comment: i put the partial view to the tbody but unfortunatelly no more changes effected. when see firebug data is recieved succefully but table not updated

Comment: i investigated again. there is completely agree with you.two tbody automatically generated behind the sense. there is no need to use $('tbody').append($(data).find('tr'));  only $('tbody').append(data); is work but before there . we should be remove <tbody></tbody> after that all is working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problems solved by only remove one of the tbody so that behind the sense generated two tbody so by avoid `<tbody></tbody>` explisitely our problems solved and its working properly.

tnx and congratulation of MR Stephen Muecke